# How can I force unattended-upgrades to run on demand?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

This is probably an easy thing to do but I found no answers while googling for it.

I have `unattended-upgrades` installed and running successfully for the past few months. It will run again tonight - but I want to run it right now.

Is there a simple command to do so?

I know it is a cron job, ideally it would execute in the same context as it always does

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, if that helps.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can execute **unattended-upgrade** with -d option to run it any time you want :)

Open terminal and execute this command:

```
sudo unattended-upgrade -d
```

It will start checking for available updates and if found it will upgrade your system.

In addition to this I also want you to go to this site:

https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html

<sup>**May 24, 2018:** Changing the URL for18.04 as 12.04 is expired.</sup>

Reply if you need any clarification.

Comment: @house9: Yes you are right :)

Comment: -d, --debug
              extra debug output into /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

Comment: The `--dry-run` may be also helpfull to see if there are any updates avaliable before actually installing them using `-d` switch.